# When calling ERC-20 token transfer() method nothing happens

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, raw-transaction

I'm currently using version 1.2.9 and Using Infura Rinkeby as Provider. So basically I'm building a node application with Inbuilt wallet. Now I have successfully Created an Account and Used that account to Send ETH transactions to other wallets by Sign Transactions and Send Transactions. Now When I have to send Contract Methods in a transaction my code thinks im sending ETH to that address my code is:

```
var contractAddress = account.asset[req.body.assetType].tokenAddress; var user_addressTo = req.body.toAccount;

var amountSent = req.body.valusent; const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI,contractAddress);

const result =   {
from: account.address,
to:user_addressTo,
value:0x00,
gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(gasPrice, 'gwei')),
gas:req.body.gasLimit,
data:myContract.methods.transfer(user_addressTo,amountSent).encodeABI()
};

var signPromise  =  await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(result,key);
var z = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signPromise.rawTransaction);
```

I have checked multiple times the values im sending In. Each Value works just fine Now the Response I get from Blockchain is

```
blockNumber: 7645527,
contractAddress: null,
cumulativeGasUsed: 494263,
from: '0xe6f2332b8758148de0e7739177544d28a4225807',
gasUsed: 21620,
logs: [],
logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
status: true,
to: '0x3dea86e3170ab1e93ff033cee4ae07bb19c75ab7',
transactionHash: '0xca08aa4560de4bae21bceaa36ed2b8c23f218ca05cf7d9adad1845ac8b817dcc',
transactionIndex: 2
```

I have followed a lot of tutorials and answers from different platforms but each gives out this result. Can you guys help me?

Comment: `Now When I have to send Contract Methods in a transaction my code thinks im sending ETH to that address` Why do you think so?

Comment: Because the transaction on  etherscan doesnt show any token transfter info It just states that 0 ETH was transferred and even in the InputData there is just a hash its not computed in functions and ID like in normal contract function call

Comment: Please give a link to the transaction as it would be *very relevant* to help you with the question.

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xca08aa4560de4bae21bceaa36ed2b8c23f218ca05cf7d9adad1845ac8b817dcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contract address does not contain any smart contract code:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x3dea86e3170ab1e93ff033cee4ae07bb19c75ab7

Please deploy your token smart contract first before using its ABI.

Comment: Ohhh... I just realized what the mistake is. In toAddress im sending address of the person im suppose to transfer token rather than address of the contract. I changed that and its working fine now !!! .Thanks brother for all the help

Comment: No problem Syed. Please mark answer closed if it solved your problem.